# 95 Integra LS fails to start: proposed "jump test"

Tags: starter, acura, integra

## CONTEXT:

A 95 Integra LS had its starter replaced 2 weeks ago.  The starter seems to be very strong / effective.

## OBSERVATIONS:

After replacing the front tie rods, the Integra would not turn over that evening: just a soft click.  The following morning, it starts and is driven around town: same startup failures are observed again.   Y

Yesterday, a buddy disconnects / reconnects the starter's control wire: he thinks it was loose.  We thought we solved the problem: the car is driven around town yesterday and again start fails in the evening.

## QUESTION

I would like to eliminate the starter as the problem.   **Is it reasonable to "jump" the starter by momentarily connecting a wire from the battery to the starter's control node?**

I'm assuming that starter's control node expects battery voltage to spin-up the starter: if this is not right, I'd like to know ASAP.

Any diagnostic suggestions are always appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the end of the solenoid on the starter, there are the two main posts: large one for power; smaller one which is the energizer wire. It is completely within reason to test the starter by jumping between these two. Since the large post has direct power from the battery, this will do exactly what you're talking about. If the starter is outside of the vehicle (off the engine) this is also a diagnostic test you can run to see if it is working. Easiest way then is to put jumper cables running from a battery, with the negative (black) attached to the body and the positive (red) attached to the large main power stud. Then take a screwdriver or wrench and bridge from the large post to the small one. You'd be looking for both the starter motor to spin as well as for it to kick out in the starting position.

Comment: @Paulster2 Always good to hear from you.  Thank you for the advice

Comment: The starter is installed in the vehicle: the question is posed, so as to avoid unnecessary removal.