# 95 Integra LS Starter Control Wiring

Tags: starting, acura, integra

[1995 Integra LS](https://tinyurl.com/integramanual) (link to Integra manual) with Manual-Transmission

The [95 Integra LS fails to start: proposed "jump test"](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/94806/95-integra-ls-fails-to-start-proposed-jump-test) was successful:

- shorting the battery to the control node starts the engine
- the starter is new and is not the problem

It seems that when the weather is cool (under 50 degrees) that it is prone to starting failure.

I am interesting in two information items:

[image]

1. What is the name or part number of the cable that controls the starter?  In the diagram above it is labeled the "BLK/HWT WIRE"

I am considering replacing the cable to eliminate the possibility of a bad connection.  I can not order the part without nomenclature ("knowing what to call it").

2. Are there any other test procedures \ known issues, I should consider before replacing the cable?

## Generic block diagram:  (not from Integra-manual)

[image]

## Block Diagram from Integra Manual

[image]

## From Integra technician manual:

[image]

`Starter Cut Relay` Test:
[image]

Comment: How about testing the starter relay?

Comment: Is a "starter cut relay" the same as a "starter relay"?  Wondering if the wiring diagram represents the 95 Integra LS?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the starter cut relay is another name for the neutral safety switch. It is a switch to prevent you from starting your car when it is in gear without the clutch pedal depressed (if manual transmission). I'm not seeing a starter relay in your diagram other than that, though, so it may be a good thing to test.

The first thing I'd test is the clutch interlock switch. This should be actuated when you depress the clutch pedal. This makes it so the starter cut relay is operable. You can test this by either bridging (bypassing) the switch through the connector, or by testing continuity when pressed and released (one way will have continuity the other will not).

If the clutch interlock switch proves good, the next step would be to test the starter cut relay. Just like the clutch interlock switch, you can remove the switch and bridge the connections to test whether it is working or not.

**NOTE:** When I say "bridge the connection", I mean to bypass the switch/relay through the wiring using a heavy enough gauge of wire to handle the load. Testing would be once your bypass is in place, turn the key to see if starting occurs. **SAFETY WARNING:** Before bridging or turning of key, ensure the transmission is in neutral and the parking brake is set for safety purposes. When you bridge the relay it may want to start directly, so be ready for it.

Either of these seem like a likely spot for a problem like you are describing. Replacing the wiring would almost certainly be the last thing I'd be doing, because this seems *highly* unlikely to be the culprit.

Comment: @Paulster2   Always grateful for your shared insights / experience.   Thank you